# How can you choose which parts of meshes are seen in front of others in the viewport?

Tags: compositing-nodes, viewlayers, npr

How can you put one object behind another, but make it so it's seen in front in the viewport AND in the final render? (for example here the eyes are behind the head but but when in rendered view you can see it infront of the head) I took this picture from twitter this is not my blender file. I just want to know how they're able to make this work.
[image]

Comment: please provide blend file so we don't have to guess what the reason is...

Answer (score 0):

One cause could be a modifier.

Like this:

[image]

if you check this: [image]

you will get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understood your question.

I have struggled with wrong z-sorting (objects appearing in front of other objects even though they are actually behind) in the viewport as well.

The solution usually was setting the blend mode in the material from "alpha blend" to "alpha hashed" or "opaque".